# How to select elements from a list and put it in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to pick all the elements inside the ul tag and push it in an array using javascript.How should I do that?

```
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Push what in an array, the element or just the text. The classname indicates that you're using jQuery, but it's not tagged with jQuery.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the DOM? It seems like you would benefit the most from a tutorial which covers that: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html

Comment: the text only. Yes I am using jquery for this. But for the above problem even JS could do.

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J5JNM/)

```
var sortable1 = document.getElementById("sortable1").children;
var array = new Array();
for(i=0; i<sortable1.length; i++) {
    array.push(sortable1[i].innerHTML);
}
```

jQuery: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/eEaRh/)

```
var lis = $("#sortable1").children();
var array = new Array();
for(i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
    array.push($(lis[i]).text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I tried it and worked for me

Answer (score 2):

using `.each()` function on jQuery will help you achieve it.

try something like :

```
  var array = [];
    $( "li" ).each(function() {
      array.push($(this).text());
    });
```

for `.each()` reference click [here](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: If i have more than one <ul>s it will pick all the <li>s then!

Comment: @user: then only select the lis you want! You always have to adjust answers to fit you particular use case.

Comment: then use `$("li.ui-state-default")` . you never specified that condition at the first place

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('sortable1').children
```

returns array-like object of li objects

Comment: Actually, it returns a HTMLCollection, which is not an array but an array-like object.

Comment: var x[] = document.getElementById('sortable1').children;

Answer (score 0):

Based on your class names, it looks like you are using jQuery...

```
var myItems = $("#sortable1").children();
```

Or, if you want the text only...

```
var myItems = [];

$("#sortable1").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    myItems.push($this.text());
});
```